# С какой функции начинается работа android application?

Tags: android, android-permissions

В многих приложениях требующих доступа в интернет можно увидеть такую ситуацию, при запуске приложения без включенного wifi или моб.интернет это приложение выводит сообщение что проверьте подключение к сети, или вообще выводит диалог о включении сети. Я пытаюсь реализовать такую функцию тоже. Но у меня возник вопрос ,какая функция запускается самой первой в приложении андроид, то есть я вот сначала думал что первой при старте запускается `onStart`, но потом нашел информацию что самой первой запускается функция `onCreate`. Помогите пожалуйста решить дилемму)) потому-что мнения расходятся.

Comment: Чьи мнения расходятся? В мануале четко написано, что метод onCreate() - самая первая фаза жизненного цикла. А уже потом идут всякие onStart().

Comment: 99% всяких "дилемм" отлично описаны [в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).Не надо ничего сидеть и самому "думать", как оно может работать - надо смотреть в документацию и быть точно уверенным.

Comment: я ее читал, а потом мне попалось несколько сайтов на которых упоминалась другая  информация, и поэтому я решил уточнить))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бетмен спешит на помощь =) Первее всех стартует класс Application, который вы можете переопределить. Для этого необходимо создать класс  Application в корневом пакете вашего приложения (именно там).

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import ru.spb.arcadia.coop.utils.FirebaseDbHelper;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public static final int GLOBAL_MODE = FirebaseDbHelper.MODE_STUDENTS;
    private static FirebaseDbHelper fdbHelper;

    public static FirebaseDbHelper getFdbHelper(){
        return fdbHelper;
    }

    public static FirebaseInstanceId getInstanceId(){ return fdbHelper.getInstanceID(); }

    public static FirebaseAuth getAuth(){
        return fdbHelper.getFirebaseAuth();
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getAuthInstance(){ return fdbHelper.getAuthInstance(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.getInstance().setAutomaticResourceManagementEnabled(true);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        fdbHelper = new FirebaseDbHelper(this, GLOBAL_MODE);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        Fresco.initialize(getApplicationContext());
//        System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True");
    }

    public static void changeSelectedDB(Context context, int mode){
        fdbHelper = new FirebaseDbHelper(context, mode);
    }
}
```

Здесь можно реализовать что-то общее для всех приложений, например, объект для работы с базой или fabric. Данные объекты будут доступны из любого участка приложения.

Так же вам нужно указать в манифесте, что вы переодпределили Application класс. Для этого в application добавьте строку:

```
    android:name=".Application"
```

Вот так =)

Comment: что-бы я без этого бетмена делал)) спасибо за скорый ответ.

Comment: не обязательно его создавать в корневом. нет, конечно логичнее всего там, но не отнюдь

Comment: я пробовал создать не в корне - получал ошибку. пришел к выводу что корректно только там его создать

Comment: Для человека, задавшего вопрос стоит отдельно сделать акцент на том, что и в классе `Application` первым выполняется колбэк `onCreate()`, потому что он имеет собственные мнения на счет жизненного цикла, которые сам себе придумывает и в вопросе эта проблема озвучена явно.